# Progress percentage for service running a shell script?

Tags: shell, service, automator

I've got a simple automator service that runs the following shell script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$f" "$f.zip"
done
```

It's really very simple: it takes each file or folder and creates a zip archive. This is the same process Archive Utility uses to create archives -- the only difference here is that I use this to zip each file/folder separately.

The problem is this:

[image]

It shows 0% completed, until all files are zipped (which is totally useless). Is there a way to modify the script to update the completed percentage shown in this menu?

Better yet, is there a way to call a custom dialog that displays a progress bar and allows for canceling, just like Archive Utility does for individual files?

Comment: The -v and -V flags for ditto will output to stderr for copied directories and files respectively, but I have no idea how to access those inside of an Automator action.   AppleScript now has status bar functionality, but I have never used it.

Comment: What automator are you using, iCal, cron etc for Mac? ditto is just a command line utility so it can't know how long it's going to take to zip each file, or how many files left to zip. I would just add a line such as 'echo archiving file $f.zip' to give you some idea of progress.

Comment: From what I've read, Archive Utility utilizes ditto to archive files, and it displays the progress bar percentage in a custom dialog quite easily.

Comment: Use ditto's `-V` as *Craig Smith* suggested and add a print after each file is completed, something like: `echo "zipping file $((i++)) of $#: $f"`.